# Java Error wrong arguments, but they are correct?

Tags: java

Okay now, I get two Errors, both the same for two methods. These ones:

```
Java: method annAmortRate in class mypack.Calculation cannot be applied to given types;
    required: double,double,double
    found: double,double
    reason: actual and formal Argument lists differ in length
```

The way I see this, this would be the case if I declared 3 doubles for my method but only delivered 2. But thats the methods:

main class:

```
double T = 0.0;
double rpy = 0.0;

if (isAnnuityLoan) {
    T = Calculation.annAmortRate(rpy, I);
} else {
    rpy = Calculation.ratePerYear(I, T);
```

I defined these two beforehand so I wouldn't get trouble with the scope of the if case.

Calculation class:

```
public static double ratePerYear(double I, double T) {

    double rpy = I + T;
    return rpy;
}


public static double annAmortRate(double rpy, double I) {

    double T = rpy - I;
    return T;
}
```

There are two defined and I deliver two. How does the Compiler expect three doubles?

Comment: Do you have an `addMortRate` method declaration taking 3 doubles in the class itself or a parent? Because the one taking 2 doubles is called `annAmortRate`...

Comment: recompile `mypack.Calculation`. It is not updated.

Comment: @mena typo, sorry for the confusion. It is also annAmortRate.

Comment: @davidxxx I'm using IntelliJ, it usually does that. How do you conclude that ist not updated? Btw, this function never used 3 variables

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It looks like there's a method with three parameters that you haven't shown us. (I'd also strongly suggest starting to follow Java naming conventions.)

Comment: have you multiple Calculation class in your project with method annAmortRate, which requires 3 double arguments?

Comment: Look at the import, it is probably an other class Calculation. Doing a clean before building migth also remove compiled rubbish too.

Comment: @joopEggen you solved it. there was another Folder on the same Directory as src in which intellJ shifted part of my classes, including a Version of Calculation.java

Comment: Eclipse does this too. It keeps showing errors which are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

There was another Folder on the same Directory as src in which intellJ shifted part of my classes, including a Version of Calculation.java